# html javascript get length name in div

Tags: javascript, html

I need a return count of elements for example name "A"

```
<div id="box">
  <input name="A" value="123">
  <input name="A" value="456">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var ii = document.getElementById("box");
  var hh = ii.getElementsByName('A');
  alert(hh.length); // should return 2 but return TypeError
</script>
```

**result:** `TypeError: ii.getElementsByName is not a function`

Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `querySelectorAll('[name=A]')` as `getElementsByName()` is not a function. And see that, it exactly gives the count of `A` inside of the `div` with id `box` since we use `ii.querySelectorAll` which selects element from the reference of `ii`.

```js
var ii = document.getElementById("box");
var hh = ii.querySelectorAll('[name=A]')
alert(hh.length);
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <input name="A" value="123">
  <input name="A" value="456">
</div>
<div id="box2">
  <input name="A" value="123">
  <input name="A" value="456">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
var ii = document.querySelectorAll("#box > input[name='A']");
alert(ii.length); // 2
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <input name="A" value="123">
  <input name="A" value="456">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByName is document's function.

```
var ii = document.getElementById("box");
var hh = document.getElementsByName('A');
alert(hh.length);
```

or use jquery：

$("#box input[name='A']").length;

Comment: This will not help OP as he wants to only get the length of 'A's in #box - there might be other A's on the page that you would count with your answer.

Comment: yes,i mean the "getElementsByName" is document's function, not "ii" 's function. about the question he can use jquery code like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll`

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('#box [name*="A"]').length);
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <input name="A" value="123">
  <input name="A" value="456">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and pass the hierarchy selector

```js
  var hh = document.querySelectorAll("#box [name='A']");
  console.log(hh.length); // logs 2
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <input name="A" value="123">
  <input name="A" value="456">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get count of input elements whose attribute name is [name= A]. Try below code.

`const count = document.querySelectorAll('#box > input[name="A"]').length;
  console.log(count);`